# How many threads does the JVM fork when it is started?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, real-time

I am just trying to avoid context switching as it introduces a lot of latency. So If I am thinking that correctly, I want to have at maximum one thread per processor. If the processor supports virtual parallelism (hyper-threading I think it is the name!) then I can have the double number of threads.

Ex: 4 processors with hyperthreading = 8 threads max.

Of course the OS needs the processor as well, so I am maybe being naive here.

Anyways, knowing the number of threads the JVM creates on startup is a good start.

Comment: Yes, you are a bit naive there. GC will always cause some latency, no matter how many CPUs you have, although some GC algorithms can reduce it in multi-processor systems. If you want guaranteed low latency, avoid Java. (And preferably all non-realtime OSes.)

Comment: Slightly off topic, hence a comment. "So If I am thinking that correctly, I want to have at maximum one thread per processor"
That's actually not as good idea as you think unless your threads will be working 100% all the time and never take locks, wait for I/O or anything else. Of course you shouldn't overdo it but in most cases, the result of trying to keep the thread count as low as the number of cores or HW-threads is just not going to give you full utilization of the CPU(s).

Comment: "I am just trying to avoid context switching as it introduces a lot of latency". Does it? Have you measured?

Comment: @EJP - yeah, last time I looked, context-switching was there to reduce latency, (well, IO latency, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM only starts 1 user thread, also called the "Main" thread.  There are other threads that are running behind the scenes such as garbage collectors, compilers, optimizers, finalizers, etc..

A quick look at a thread dump for a nothing little app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(100000);
}
```

Shows:

```
"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=5 tid=7f810c801000]
"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=9 tid=7f810c800000
"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=9 tid=7f8107037000
"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 tid=7f8107036000
"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon prio=5 tid=7f8107801000 
"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=7f810882a000 nid=0x1118cb000 
"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=7f8108829000 nid=0x1117c8000 
"main" prio=5 tid=7f8104801000 nid=0x109a52000 waiting on condition
"VM Thread" prio=9 tid=7f8108824800 nid=0x1116c5000 runnable 
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8104802800
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8104803000 
"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8104803800 
"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8107800000 
"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8108800000 
"Gang worker#5 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8107000800
"Gang worker#6 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8107001000
"Gang worker#7 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f8107002000 
"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" prio=9 tid=7f810701c000
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f81090c3000
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=9 tid=7f810701b800
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=7f810c812800 
"Exception Catcher Thread" prio=10 tid=7f8104801800
```

Comment: Assuming I want to avoid context switching by providing one processor to each thread, is it worth knowing the total number of threads the JVM creates besides this single user thread?

Comment: I don't think so @JohnPristine.  If you are asking how many user threads you should run to "maximize" your application then I'd allot 1 for the garbage collector.  None of the rest should take up any significant time.

Comment: But of course depending on what you put in your `finalize()` methods (an infinite loop for example :)), the finalizer thread can take up a whole core itself too.

Comment: Uh sure @biziclop.  Although use of `finalize()` is frowned upon: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET12-J.+Do+not+use+finalizers

Comment: I certainly frown upon it. :) Just demonstrating how fragile the OP's approach is.